# Blink.jl is removed from Project.toml but can't be removed from Manifest.toml

Tags: julia

I am trying to remove Blink from my project but can't get it even after rebuilding my manifest file:

```
(Tibra) pkg> status --outdated -m
Project Tibra v0.0.0
Status `~/src/tibra/Tibra.jl/Manifest.toml`
⌃ [ad839575] Blink v0.12.5 (<v0.12.8)
⌃ [09d831e3] GraphQLClient v0.7.5 (<v0.7.6)
⌅ [cd3eb016] HTTP v0.9.17 (<v1.9.14): GraphQLClient, Mux, Temporal, WebSockets
⌅ [a975b10e] Mux v0.7.6 (<v1.0.1): Blink
⌅ [2913bbd2] StatsBase v0.33.21 (<v0.34.0): HawkesProcesses
⌃ [104b5d7c] WebSockets v1.5.9 (<v1.6.0)
⌃ [b22a6f82] FFMPEG_jll v4.4.2+2 (<v4.4.4+1)
⌅ [e9f186c6] Libffi_jll v3.2.2+1 (<v3.4.4+0): Glib_jll, HarfBuzz_jll, Wayland_jll
⌅ [458c3c95] OpenSSL_jll v1.1.22+0 (<v3.0.10+0): FFMPEG_jll, LibPQ_jll, MongoC_jll, Qt6Base_jll
⌅ [214eeab7] fzf_jll v0.29.0+0 (<v0.35.1+0): JLFzf

(Tibra) pkg> rm Blink
ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:
 * Blink (ad839575-38b3-5650-b840-f874b8c74a25 in manifest but not in project)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Manifest.toml` file records all transitive dependencies of your project, while the `Project.toml` file is for direct dependencies. That's why package operations like `add` or `rm` only operate on the `Project.toml` directly, while any changes to the `Manifest.toml` file happen after Pkg has resolved the environment based on what you specify in the `Project.toml`.

Therefore, if you want to remove `Blink` from your manifest, you will have to remove whatever direct dependcy you have in your `Project.toml` that depends on `Blink` - since Julia 1.9 you can do this using `pkg> why Blink`.

Here's an example, I added `FloatinTableView` to an empty environment, here's the `Project.toml`:

```
(jl_5rmgNJ) pkg> st
Status `Temp\jl_5rmgNJ\Project.toml`
  [197bc772] FloatingTableView v0.2.0
```

now looking at the `Manifest.toml`:

```
(jl_5rmgNJ) pkg> st -m
Status `Temp\jl_5rmgNJ\Manifest.toml`
  [bf4720bc] AssetRegistry v0.1.0
  [d1d4a3ce] BitFlags v0.1.7
  [ad839575] Blink v0.12.8
  [944b1d66] CodecZlib v0.7.2
  [3da002f7] ColorTypes v0.11.4
(...)
```

It's much longer than this as `FloatingTableView` has a bunch of dependencies, but you see that it pulled in `Blink`. Now if I didn't know it had been pulled in by `FloatingTableView`, I could find out like this:

```
(jl_5rmgNJ) pkg> why Blink
  FloatingTableView → Blink
```